React static export files working locally and in firebase local emulator, but not on firebase deploy
I built a react app. and did npm run build, then did firebase init too. firebase emulators:start is also working fine, and opening index.html in the build folder is working fine too. But when doing firebase deploy, its not working. in my package.json, i have also added - "homepage": "./",
the following is the error:
first error
When i am checking the sources tab in the inspector, i see the following files, second error
but not all the files from the build folders are uploaded, not even images. and only single files are uploaded from css, and js folders from the static folder.
Help me my fellow coders. What am i doing wrong?
tried deleting build folder, and all the firebase files and did firebase init and npm run build and firebase deploy, many times. didnt work.
